# midi keyboard lost 7 keys

Tags: diodes, midi

I have acquired a korg 49 key midi keyboard which has 7 keys that do not work.as set of 5 together then 2 more 2 keys away. what could cause this issue? I have cleaned and tested the contacts and they are fine. could it be one or more diodes in the matrix stopping the keys sending a signal or more likely to be a processing error or chip failure?

Comment: It could be anything. Diodes, broken wire, loose solder joint, cracked PCB so the trace is cut, damaged chip input or output, or anything. You should check what is common wire or pin for all those broken keys in the key matrix. Preferably get a service manual.

Comment: one thing you can try is reconnecting all cables (and checking them meanwhile), but the chance is something is broken like Justme answered making it harder to fix

Comment: i have checked the pcb traces and the ribbon cables connectors and solder joints. all have continuity and joints look good. there is no service manual its a £250 keyboard with no spare parts available. my electronics skill is quite low, I can do the basic trouble shooting and usually can work out what has gone bad and replace it. When it comes to ic's and multi layer pcbs i am out of my depth. i think i will have to draw out the matrix by hand .

Comment: Usually a membrane has to be changed or restored contacts, or the ribbon cable is broken, oxidized connectors of ribbon cable, almost impossible is that diodes are bad.

Comment: starting with key number 1 on left, which key numbers failed?